Cтолбец с типом данных ARRAY sqlalchemy
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему у меня не создается столбец с типом данных ARRAY?
from sqlalchemy import ARRAY 
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, DeclarativeBase, relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableList
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

engine = create_async_engine(url="postgresql+asyncpg://bot:bot@localhost:5432/bot", echo=True)
    
async_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_= AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'match'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tg_id = Column(BigInteger)
    field = Column('myarray', ARRAY(Integer), nullable=True)   
        
async def async_main():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)``` 

Возникает следующая ошибка: 

*sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedColumnError'>: столбец match.myarray не существует 
[SQL: SELECT match.id, match.tg_id, match.myarray
FROM match
WHERE match.tg_id = $1::BIGINT]
[parameters: (3221942666,)]
FROM match
WHERE match.tg_id = $1::BIGINT]
[parameters: (421942666,)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)*


столбец match.myarray не существует - на какой язык надо перевести это сообщение?

так в этом и вопрос, почему он не создается?

Отбой. Разобрался!
